# how can i fix the sql developer 'No TNS entries found' error?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

[I have just installed it and this is what I am getting. I can't even start a connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmUWK.png)

I was trying to connect to my database and I simply can not because of that error. I have already created a database and I can connect to it without any problems when is use the command prompt(SQL plus>>>sys as sys dba).

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show you trying to create a connection.  Do you have a tnsnames file that you can use on the command line?  The connection string you are using is not using a tnsnames file.  If so, where is that file?  Can you create a connection using one of the non-TNS connection methods (Basic presumably)?

Comment: That's not an error. It only means if you want to connect via TNS, you'll have to provide the location of that file in the preferences